# Retrieving names of data structure fields

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

i want to retrieve the field names of a data structure. Is that possible? My plan is to write a toString() procedure to dump a given data structure. For example i could print all field names and values of the ds as JSON.

Comment: a wonderful idea. But do not think it is possible. Only dynamic languages, that is something that allows a variable's type to be assigned at run time, provide a way for a program to list the properties of a variable.

Comment: @RockBoro you may be surprised, check out my answer. ;)

Comment: @RockBoro - That's not correct. There is nothing at all to prevent a statically typed language from exposing the properties of a variable at run time. Not all statically typed languages do this, but it's just a design decision, not a technical issue. Indeed, the fact that types are frozen at compile time would make this even easier for a statically typed language to do (if it chose to) than a dynamically typed one (which often needs to).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While RPG doesn't truly support "reflection" like C# for instance does, in the last few years IBM has added ["open access"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasm/roaMain.htm) functionality.

Originally, open access worked with file I/O op-codes.  Then IBM for v7.2+ added the [DATA-INTO](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasd/zzdatainto.htm) op-code for parsing into a data structure.  In the fall of 2019 for v7.3+ IBM added the  [DATA-GEN](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasd/zzdatagen.htm) op-code for generating from a data structure.

You're free to code your own parser or generator.

However, Scott Klement has kindly provided a parser (YAJLINTO) and generator (YAJLDTAGEN) into his and David Russo's original open source IBM i port of ["Yet Another JSON Library (YAJL)"](http://www.scottklement.com/yajl/).

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll take a look at it:)

Comment: @bensen don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you feel it answered your question.